# What happens if you try to apparate into Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter

We learn that using apparition into and out of Hogwarts is not possible.
When Dumbledore is using apparition with Harry when they are going to find the locket, Harry asks him how can he do that, and he says that it's something a headmaster can do.

When an instructor from the Ministry Of Magic arrives at Hogwarts to teach apparition to the students, Dumbledore says that it is now possible to apparate inside the dining hall, and warns them that they should not try to apparate outside of the room, and makes it sound dangerous.

Does it ever say what will happen if someone tries to apparate into Hogwarts?

Comment: @Rebel-Scum I would imagine they would go into non-existence or something, but I like your guess better.

Comment: Probably nothing. Perhaps a nosebleed or something.

Comment: Your entire body explodes and you die. And that's just for starters

Comment: You would possibly apparate at a random place near Hogwarts. Or it just won’t work at all

Comment: A one-way ticket to Azkaban.

Comment: I don't know if you're still active, but can you accept my canonically-correct answer?

Answer (score 10):

In Chapter Eighteen of *Half-Blood Prince* when the Ministry instructor explained that the anti-apparition enchantment had been lifted from the Great Hall for them to practice, he said:

> May I emphasize that you will not be able to Apparate outside the walls of this Hall, and that you would be unwise to try.

The implication here seems to be that if you do try to Apparate against the enchantment, some unspecified bad thing will happen to you.

However, in the two instances in which we actually see people trying to Apparate against enchantments, nothing actually seems to happen to them. In Chapter Twenty-Three of *Deathly Hallows*:

> Ron was now trying to Disapparate without a wand.
>
> "There's no way out, Ron," said Luna, watching his fruitless efforts.

In Chapter Twenty-Eight of *Deathly Hallows*:

> The air through which they needed to move seemed to have become solid: They could not Disapparate; the Death Eaters had cast their charms well.

While neither of these two events occur at Hogwarts, we have no reason to assume that the anti-apparition charms at Hogwarts are fundamentally different from anti-apparition charms used elsewhere. Indeed, in Chapter Four of *Half-Blood Prince* Dumbledore mentions Hogwarts as an example of the anti-apparition charms placed on most Wizarding dwellings, implying that it is the same enchantment:

> In any case, most Wizarding dwellings are magically protected from unwanted Apparators. At Hogwarts, for instance —"
>
> "— you can't Apparate anywhere inside the buildings or grounds," said Harry quickly. "Hermione Granger told me."

It would therefore seem that nothing happens when you try to Apparate where there are anti-apparition enchantments in place. The Ministry instructor may have simply been trying to scare them into behaving.

(Montague did nearly die trying to Apparate out of the Vanishing Cabinet, but that was not necessarily related to the fact that Hogwarts had an anti-apparition enchantment.)

Comment: In both of those examples (certainly in the 2nd) it sounds like there is something else blocking them from disapparating, not that they are running into the normal Hogwarts blocking, so I don't know if they give useful information about what happens if someone runs into Hogwarts' own defences.

Comment: @DavidW What indicates that those are anything more than the standard anti-apparition charms?

Comment: That was precisely my point!  If a standard charm blocked those attempts to apparate, then they tell us nothing about what *Hogwarts'* effect on an attempt is, because it never reached that point.

Comment: @DavidW I would agree with you if we had reason to believe that the enchantments at Hogwarts are fundamentally different from those in other locations. I have edited the answer to make it more clear that I am equating the protections at Hogwarts with those elsewhere.

Comment: If there were a normal and cruel version of the anti-apparition charms, I would have expected the Death Eaters to use the nastier one.

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but from the wording it looks like your examples might be pointing in opposite directions - nothing happens when trying to leave a warded area (disapparate), some unspecified bad thing may, or may not, happen when trying to enter one (apparate).  I don't think there's better evidence, mind, I just noticed the directionality.

Comment: "The Ministry instructor may have simply been trying to scare them into behaving." JK Rowling has stated there are disastrous effects on Pottermore. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

### It can cause disastrous effects.

In the books, the ministry instructor warns students not to even try:

> May I emphasize that you will not be able to Apparate outside the walls of this Hall, and that you would be unwise to try.

As an instructor, he would presumably know what he's talking about.

Furthermore, in Pottermore's *Hogwarts: An Incomplete and Unreliable Guide* it says:

> As we know from early historical accounts, and from the evidence of early woodcuts and engravings, Hogwarts students used to arrive at school in any manner that caught their fancy. Some rode broomsticks (a difficult feat when carrying trunks and pets); others commandeered enchanted carts and, later, carriages; **some attempted to Apparate (often with disastrous effects, as the castle and grounds have always been protected with Anti-Apparition Charms)**; others rode a variety of magical creatures.

So we see that there are times where "disastrous effects" happen when apparating into a protected zone.

In the books, as Alex points out, nothing happens. But that just means that those times nothing happened. (as the Hogwarts Guide points out, disastrous effects "often" happen, not always.)

(Furthermore, it's possible that the anti-apparation charm in Hogwarts in unique, but that's unlikely, as Dumbledore explicitly compares private anti-apparation charms to Hogwarts' in *Half-Blood Prince*.)

Comment: *In the books, as Alex points out, nothing happens. But that just means that those times nothing happened.* Or that JK Rowling didn’t read the books.

Comment: @Alex Maybe. But it doesn't directly go against the books either.

Comment: I've always pictured it like throwing a water balloon against a brick wall.  Pieces and juice just bouncing off in all directions.  In a sense... messy :P